# Regarding casting of the outcome

Tags: java, string, int

I have a method which return type is string below is the method

```
public String getHwIdentifier();
```

Now I am using this method ..

```
String s = till.getHwIdentifier();//return type of this method is string
```

I want to cast it in integer that is something like this

```
Int i = till.getHwIdentifier();
```

Please advise how take integer means how to cast it..

Comment: You probably mean int (java primitive type) or Integer instead of Int?

Answer (score 1):

try parseInt from Integer class.

```
Integer.parseInt(till.getHwIdentifier());
```

but mind you, it'd throw `NumberFormatException` if the string is not a valid integer representation

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt(String s)` method of `Integer` class which takes `String` and converts it to `int`if it is a number or throws `NumberFormatException` like this :

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(till.getHwIdentifier());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the instance of the `String` to `Integer.valueOf(String s)`.
So in your case:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(till.getHwIdentifier);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java type/class named `Int`. There's `int` type and it's encapsulating `Integer` class.

You can parse an integer in a `String` to the `int` value with `Integer.parseInt("1234");`, or get the `Integer` value with `Integer.valueOf("1234");`. But notice if the `String` doesn't represent an integer you'll get a `NumberFormatException`.

```
    String s = till.getHwIdentifier();//return type of this method is string;
    try
    {
      Integer a = Integer.valueOf(s);
      int b = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
      //...
    }
```

---

Note: You could use `Integer a = Integer.decode(s);`, but `Integer c = Integer.valueOf(s);` is preferred as it won't create new objects if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = till.getHwIdentifier();
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Make sure that your string is in the form of an integer. If your string contains xyz then you will get a java.lang.NumberFormatException.